# Excel VBA Check if value is "#N/A"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset which is an extract from a SQL DB. One of the goals of my macro is to check if a specific data field contained "#N/A". I have found that the data as extracted is not recognized by excel as an Excel #N/A error but it seems to think it's a string.
If I try to check if a cell contains #N/A on the extracted data I get the following:

- actual worksheet function `=ISNA(cell which contains #N/A)` results in FALSE
- VBA: `If .range(cell which contains #N/A) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`
  I get `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

However, if I physically go to the cell with "#N/A", select the cell, hit F2, hit Enter and then rerun the VBA I no longer get the Run-time error. The worksheet formula also returns TRUE after physically selecting the cell and hitting Enter.

I can use VBA to try to look for the String "#N/A" but if I edited the data before running the VBA, I also get a error because now the cell value is the true #N/A error (Error 2042).

Is there a way to automatically get Excel to recognize the string "#N/A" as the Excel error without physically selecting each cell, or manually copy/pasting?

Comment: `If IsError(.range()) Then`?

Comment: Also sounds like your calculations are set to manual.  calculate the sheet before testing the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the string in a way to make `IsNA` working. Please, test the next way:

```
  Dim actC As Range: Set actC = ActiveCell
  
  With actC
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value  'it simulates the editing...
  End With
  Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.IsNA(actC.Value)
```

`actC` can be the whole range you want (firstly) converting...